# Object deletion responsibility in a hierarchy of objects

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I have three types of objects: **T, X and Y**

- X creates object of type T on heap and this object is pointed to by private member pointer of class X
- Y creates object of type X on heap but needs to manipulate heap object T created by heap object X

  - Y can either use a private member pointer to store copy of pointer to heap object T of heap object X
  - or Y can use a local pointer to store copy of pointer to heap object T of heap object X

To cleanup the objects, I can think of following two methods

**Method 1**

- Y deletes X in its destructor
- X deletes T in its destructor

**Method 2**

- Y deletes X in its destructor
- Y deletes X.T through its member pointer in the destructor
- or Y deletes X.T through local pointer inside the local function where it is used

Which of the above two methods is a preferred way to delete objects ?

Comment: It seems pure encapsulation that `Y` needs direct access to `T`. Why not provide the needed functionality for that in `X` and let `T` be an implementation detail.

Comment: I agree with both replies that say use Method 1.  But you could avoid the problem entirely by using std::shared_ptr.

Comment: @MobyDisk: I donot want to use shared_ptr as I would be running my code later on a GPU (no C++11 support)

Comment: @pmr: I agree. chmod_007 says the same thing. Another what-if question is "what if Y needs to only READ X.T and not manipulate X.T". Would your recommendation be the same in that case ?

Comment: @nurabha Then I think `X` should provide an accessor member function that only hands out a reference to const `const T& get_t() const`

Comment: @pmr: I was thinking on same lines. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 sounds preferable. If type X allocates a type T member, the deletion of that T should absolutely happen in the destructor of type X. Otherwise, using Method 2, if you decide down the line to create a new type that has a member of type X, you will have to remember to delete the type T in the new constructor. This could lead to memory leaks and code that is difficult to maintain.

Also, If Y needs to manipulate T, it should do so through member functions of type X since T is a private member of X. That way, Type Y does not need its own pointer to the type T object.

Comment: your last statement makes lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Every thing must work on own task.

In your case, Y call X destructor and X destroy its own resources.